# Index breaks in a set

Tags: python

I'm writing a python script that takes a text file like the following as input:

```
0   A   (*) Begin
1   A
2   A
3   A
4   A
5   A   (*) End
0   B   (*) Begin
1   B
2   B
3   B
4   B
5   B
6   B   (*) End
0   B   (*) Begin
1   B
2   B   (*) End
0   B   (*) Begin
1   B
2   B
3   B
4   B   (*) End
```

Now I'd like to receive the output like this one:

```
0   A   (*) Begin [0]
1   A
2   A
3   A
4   A
5   A   (*) End [0]
0   B   (*) Begin [0]
1   B
2   B
3   B
4   B
5   B
6   B   (*) End [0]
0   B   (*) Begin [1]
1   B
2   B   (*) End [1]
0   B   (*) Begin [2]
1   B
2   B
3   B
4   B   (*) End [2]
```

that would be the translation of:

```
>>>A = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
>>>A
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>>len(A)
6
>>>B = [(0,1,2,3,4,5,6), (0,1,2), (0,1,2,3,4)]
>>>B
[(0,1,2,3,4,5,6), (0,1,2), (0,1,2,3,4)]
>>>len(B[0])
7
>>>len(B[1])
3
>>>len(B[2])
5
```

I tried for now in this way:

```
import sys, os
import os.path

txtdir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
path = os.path.join(txtdir, 'txt/')

textfile = "%sfile.txt" % (path)
with open(textfile,"r") as f:
    # read a LIST of rows into "data"
    data = f.readlines()

previous_col = ''
current_col = ''
for row in data:
    match_1 = "(*) Begin"
    match_2 = "(*) End"
    if (match_1 in row or match_2 in row):
        col = row.split()
        print col
        print len(col)

        if (col[3] == "End"):
            previous_col = col[1]
        elif (col[3] == "Begin"):
            current_col = col[1]

        i = 0
        if current_col:
            if (col[3] == "Begin" and current_col == previous_col):
                i += 1 # increment
                col[3] = "Begin [%s]" % (i)
            else:
                col[3] = "Begin [0]"

# and write everything back
with open(textfile, 'w') as f:
    f.writelines( data )

# close f file
f.close()
```

But there is no change into "file.txt"

May you suggest me something?

Thanks a lot,

Riccardo

Comment: `textfile = "%sfile.txt" % (path)` ... Are you adding a `/` at the end of the path?

Comment: Reduce it to the minimum code which still doesn't work.

Comment: You don't need to `close` explicitly as you are using `with ... `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from the obvious issue pointed out by Paul Lo that you're not updating `data` list at all, you're in my opinion over-complicating this stuff, you can do this simply using [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter

c = Counter()

with open('file.txt') as f, open('outfile.txt', 'w') as out:
    for line in f:
        # In `if` and `elif`, use the current value of the counter
        # for the second column, default is 0.   
        if '(*) Begin' in line:
            text = line.split(None, 2)[1]
            out.write('{}[{}]\n'.format(line.strip(), c[text]))
        elif '(*) End' in line:
            text = line.split(None, 2)[1]
            out.write('{}[{}]\n'.format(line.strip(), c[text]))
            # End found, so now increment the counter  
            c[text] += 1
        else:
            out.write(line)
```

Also to modify the same file in-place I would recommend using the  [`fileinput`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fileinput.html) module:

```
from collections import Counter
import fileinput

c = Counter()

for line in  fileinput.input('file1.txt', inplace=True):
    if '(*) Begin' in line:
        text = line.split(None, 2)[1]
        print '{}[{}]'.format(line.strip(), c[text])
    elif '(*) End' in line:
        text = line.split(None, 2)[1]
        print '{}[{}]'.format(line.strip(), c[text])
        # End found, so now increment the counter  
        c[text] += 1
    else:
        print line,
```

**Output:**

```
0   A   (*) Begin[0]
1   A
2   A
3   A
4   A
5   A   (*) End[0]
0   B   (*) Begin[0]
1   B
2   B
3   B
4   B
5   B
6   B   (*) End[0]
0   B   (*) Begin[1]
1   B
2   B   (*) End[1]
0   B   (*) Begin[2]
1   B
2   B
3   B
4   B   (*) End[2]
```

Comment: Perfect! Tested! Thanks so much, Ashwini :-)

Answer (score 2):

You made lots of work in `for row in data`, but you didn't really make any changes on `data` (or `row`), you just write the origin stuff back to the file again, that's why it looks like nothing has changed. And your modification on `col` which comes from `col = row.split()`, that would not change `row` and `data` as well.

Without changing too much on your code, you probably want to fix it by this way which use another `list` for saving the updated lines:

```
textfile = "%sfile.txt" % (path)
with open(textfile,"r") as f:
    # read a LIST of rows into "data"
    data = f.readlines()
previous_col = ''
current_col = ''
lst = list()  # for the new content you are going to override
for row in data:
    match_1 = "(*) Begin"
    match_2 = "(*) End"
    if (match_1 in row or match_2 in row):
        col = row.split()
        if (col[3] == "End"):
            previous_col = col[1]
        elif (col[3] == "Begin"):
            current_col = col[1]

        i = 0
        if current_col:
            if (col[3] == "Begin" and current_col == previous_col):
                i += 1 # increment
                col[3] = "Begin [%s]" % (i)
            else:
                col[3] = "Begin [0]"

        lst.append(' '.join(col)) # you can adjust it to the behavior you need
   else:  # append original line
        lst.append(row)  

# and write everything back
with open(textfile, 'w') as f:
    for line in lst:  # write the element in lst to the file
          f.writelines(line)
          f.writelines('\n')
```

Comment: Paul, Thanks for the review of my code! Testing it, I saw that the numbering is not exactly what I proposed, but it works. Thank You!

Comment: @Riccardo You're welcome, it shows the general idea and might need some more slight changes.